# Debug QGIS crash on Windows 7 - how?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, windows-7, debugging

I'm developing a QGIS plugin, and under certain circumstances, it causes QGIS itself to crash. How can I debug this, given that I am on Windows 7? I've tried using the QGIS nightly dev build (which the QGIS dev site said had debug enabled), but dbgview.exe could not read any debug output from the dump file. How can I debug this further?

The issue in question is here: https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/32

Answer (score 2):

You'll find it MUCH easier to debug under Linux. You could:

- setup a virtual machine running a linux distro. I'd suggest Ubuntu as it's easy to get the dependencies installed
- setup a built environment using QtCreator. Instructions are in the CODING file in the QGIS source (or they can be viewed on online here: https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.github.com/qgis/QGIS/master/doc/CODING.html#toc54)
- Follow the instructions in the CODING file for "Running and Debugging" (online here: https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.github.com/qgis/QGIS/master/doc/CODING.html#toc59 )

Comment: OK, same advice as given on qgis-dev. I'll have to do that, I guess.

Comment: Just in case it's of any use, I managed to read the dump file on Win7. I don't know if any of this helps point to the problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u66fqfre4073uhi/qgis_dump.txt?dl=0